# Using max-height with border-box

Tags: css

Why isn't `max-height` applied on the box in [this example](http://jsbin.com/EhIxITE/1/edit) ? It seems like that the border-box mode is ignored (tested on Chrome), but it seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 5):

The `box-sizing` property isn't ignored, this is exactly how the `border-box` value should behave:

Your padding is set to 100px on top and bottom, therefore 200px of your element's `height` is **consumed** by the padding.

If you specify a `height` of 200px, the computed height will be 0 because 200 - 200 is 0.

If you specify a `height` of 201px, the computed height will be 1, etc.

From the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) documentation:

> The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the padding widths of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’ properties. **As the content width and height cannot be negative, this computation is floored at 0.**

This is easily demonstrated using borders instead of padding:

```css
#test {
  background: #000;
  border-width: 100px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here our element has a black background and a red border, however as its height is equal to the sum of the top and bottom border widths, the element ends up with 0px computed:

[image: Example 1]

As you can see, the box is entirely red. The element has no height so there is no black background to be seen. If we adjust the element's `height` to `250px`, we end up with:

[image: Example 2]

The element's computed height here is 50px, so we see 50px of the background. The remaining 200px is consumed by the border.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. However, the standard also says that, when using border-box, *"The specified width and height **(and respective min/max properties)** on this element determine the border box of the element"*. If the max-height is applied to the content box height only, isn't it wrong in regard to the standard ?

Comment: @MaëlNison at this point it's probably worth noting that the `box-sizing` is only [partially supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) in the majority of browsers. The documentation is a working draft, not a recommendation, meaning its implementation is put down to what the browser developers interpret of it, and its content is subject to change.

Comment: I see this answer as plain wrong. `border-box` means the height includes padding. What you're calling the "calculated height" is content's height. `max-height` should referer to the same height the `height` refers to, not some other "calculated height".

Comment: To compensate for max-height ignoring box-sizing and only being applied to content, you need to nest a "content" div inside the max-height div..  the content div is where border and padding are applied

Comment: What this answer lacks is an advice on how to actually achieve what is obviously desired here: the ability to overridingly force an element to be effectively visually no taller than the given value (0 in this case), without using wrapper elements, and without having to control for multiple variables like padding, margin and whatever else.